# How to build custom shell for windows7, wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, windows-shell

How can I make my own shell for windows 7?

That will run in fullscreen mode and act something like windows media center.

What I want to achieve is a kind of application menu. After OS starts, shell will boot so the user can choose and run apps from the shell. When they are closed, user returns back to shell.

I've found no information on how to implement custom shells. Does anyone know where should I start with it?

I understand that it may require some c/c++ code, but i'd like to code in c#, wpf mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full screen application will probably enough for you.

To truly replace shell you need to change setting like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell. Please search and read about making changes to this key... you still may be able to use task manager to bring regular explorer back if you change the value incorrectly.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, which was "How to write a replacement shell for Windows?". Writing a full-screen WPF app isn't replacing the shell.

Comment: Yes, I want to write a replacement shell.

Comment: The comment is chosen while it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Good point. Actually the question is currently off-topic (too broad) for SO, so really does not matter too much. The only answerable part could be "how to set you program to be shell", the rest is either too broad or duplicate of something like "how to use `Process.Start`".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But isn't there a well-known APIs or techinques to write a Shell? For example, [subclassing tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056258) isn't going to help when there's no `explorer.exe` running. I think there should be at least an explanation on how does GUI subsystem in Windows work (i.e. first we're calling `user32.dll` etc, but where's the code that draws windows' boundaries?)

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph or maybe long discussion on what "shell" means for different people (i.e. does it have to have windows/GUI or command line is fine too), or security concerns, or whether lack of drag'n'drop support will make program "not really shell"... OP found my answer somewhat useful (as it marked accepted) so I'll keep it, but I would not even try to answer it now if similar question comes up.