# Setting a callback for tray icon message handling in a console project

Tags: winapi, callback

I was used to using WndProc for handling proc messages, but now I have a console project and I want somehow to handle a custom `WM_TRAYICON` message.

I have the callback function, I just need to make Windows call it whenever someone interacts with the tray icon. In a recent program I did I used `SetWindowsHookEx`, can something similar be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a hidden window to use with the notification icon. Call `CreateWindow` as usual to create a window, but just refrain from showing it. Make sure that you do not pass `WS_VISIBLE` when creating the window.

The other issue is that you need a message loop. Since a console application will not run a message loop by default, the simplest solution is to run the notification icon out of a separate thread which implements the message loop. Naturally this implies that the hidden window needs to be created and destroyed in that thread also.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you do not make your project console. If you want to handle window messages in legitimate way (without hooks and hacks) and you want to have a console then typical solution is to use [AllocConsole](http://I%20propose%20you%20do%20not%20make%20your%20project) function.

Comment: Console apps can perfectly legitimately use windows and message loops. Creating a hidden window to handle the message (likely on its own thread) is the simplest way to go here if the OP need the app to remain a console app.